# Write content of LinkedList in a txt file.

Tags: c++

So I have the following code in which I print out the content of linked list, however I'm trying to write it in a file. I successfully read off a file and created the linkedlist but now I'm stuck in how to write it back into another file.

```
void LinkedList::printAll()
{
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"There are no nodes in the list"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *tmp = p;
        cout<<endl<< "RUID    Name"<<endl;

        while(tmp!=NULL)
        {
            cout <<tmp->ID <<"\t"<<tmp->name<<endl;
            tmp=tmp->next;
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

This is what I'm trying to write in a file instead of printing out. Any help would be wonderful.

This is what it should look like

RUID Name
4325 Omar
5432 Partha
6530 Rani
1034 Esha
2309 Rana
3214 Badri

Comment: As far as the write operations go you basically write it the same way you print it on to the screen. The only difference is instead of using `cout` you use an `ofstream` object, open a file and write.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code generator, and _"any help would be wonderful"_ is not a question. This is a Q&A, not a chatroom.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not looking for a solution. This is my first time reading and writing from a file using C++. I know how to write a statement or read a file and write it.... but But needed little help in how to write the content of a linkedlist into a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is change the output stream you're writing from `cout` to a file stream.

A better approach to your `printAll` function would be something like this:

```
#include <ostream>
//...
void LinkedList::printAll(std::ostream& os)
{
    if(p==NULL)
    {
        os<<"There are no nodes in the list"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *tmp = p;
        os<<endl<< "RUID    Name"<<endl;

        while(tmp!=NULL)
        {
            os <<tmp->ID <<"\t"<<tmp->name<<endl;
            tmp=tmp->next;
        }
    }
    os<<endl;
}
```

Then if we want to print to the console:

```
LinkedList t;
//...
t.printAll(cout);
```

and to print to a file:

```
LinkedList t;
//...
std::ofstream ofs("myfile.txt");
t.printAll(ofs);
```